# Ray effect animation behind buttons in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button

Is there any way to create a ray animation behind buttons in Android like [this](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-spin) javascript-demo.

It should just rotate behind the `Button` when it is clicked but shouldn't extend the content area of the view (float behind the `Button`).

[image: rotating ray]
That rays should rotate within the rectangle of the parent layout.

Any easy way to do it?

My code:

```
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLParamsCont = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Utils.dpToPx(getContext(), 50));
    LLParamsCont.setMargins(Utils.dpToPx(getContext(), 5), Utils.dpToPx(getContext(), 5), Utils.dpToPx(getContext(), 5), Utils.dpToPx(getContext(), 5));
    LLParamsCont.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    RelativeLayout cont = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    cont.setLayoutParams(LLParamsCont);

            /* This image view should extend its available space without change the parents dimensions and animate */
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunray);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    cont.addView(imageView);

            /* Trying it with that code, but the imageview is behind the button and only visible a view pixel
               Increasing the parent will be a mess with other buttons, the rays should just overlap a litle bit all other elements in the back.
               The final rays will be a more alpha transparent ...*/
    Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotate);
    imageView.startAnimation(rotate);


    Button btn = new Button(getContext());
      btn.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      btn.setText("Button");

      cont.addView(btn);
```

Comment: Are you looking to do it in Java or Android?

Comment: Use an AnimationDrawable (Rotation) as the background for the Button's parent. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Comment: Hello @Juwei  ... did you find the solution ?!

Answer (score 2):

Just creating your own animations:
Follow this example create shake.xml in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromXDelta="0" 
        android:toXDelta="10" 
            android:duration="1000" 
                android:interpolator="@anim/cycle" />
```

and cycle.xml in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:cycles="4" />
```

now add animation on your code

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
anyview.startAnimation(shake);
```

If you want vertical animation, change fromXdelta and toXdelta value to fromYdelta and toYdelta value.

Check out [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/02/apply-animation-on-button.html) tutorial. He has ways of different animations

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is the cut off of the rotation image, in example:
I have a imageview in a relativelayout view and want to rotate it so that it is centered and cut off the border of the parent layout.

Comment: I have added a sample picture to my question above.

Comment: Ok i guess you only want to animate the background/linearlayout or image you have. Can you put the xml distribution on the parent layout?

Comment: Added my code snippet above. Please take a look. With your animation sample the imageview is rotating but its not visible (or just a view pixels) because it can't extend its parents boundarys.

Comment: Please post your xml code, it is a boundaries problem so may the layout not be well defined.

Comment: Theres no xml, i am doing it all by code. There are weighted linear-layouts adding the buttons container. The buttons container (cont above) are created dynamically one after one. The container was nessesary because i place another element inside the button dynamically and needed a relativelayout for this.

But the main problem seems that its not possible to extend the image view over the boundaries, right? Will this be possible if i remove the imageview from that structure and place it absoluteley by x/y position of the buttons center?

Comment: Ok I've never do it by hardcode, I guess, Yes by placing the position actually where you want may solve the boundaries.
Try snippet: 
`myButton.setX(<x value>);
myButton.setY(<y value>);`